# Counting Neighbors (Why scipy.signal.convolve2D so fast?)

Tags: python, performance, game-of-life

Here is my Python implementation of counting neighbours of Game of Life with radius as parameter.

```
def neighbors_count(n2d_array, radii=1):
    assert n2d_array.ndim == 2
    row_len, col_len = n2d_array.shape
    nbrs_count = np.zeros_like(n2d_array)
    for row_idx, row_val in enumerate(n2d_array):
         for col_idx, col_val in enumerate(row_val):
             start_row = 0 if (row_idx-radii) < 0 else (row_idx-radii)
             end_row = row_len if (row_idx+radii+1) > row_len else (row_idx+radii+1)
             start_col = 0 if (col_idx-radii) < 0 else (col_idx-radii)
             end_col = row_len if (col_idx+radii+1) > row_len else (col_idx+radii+1)
             neighbor = 0
             for block_row_idx in np.arange(start_row, end_row):
                 for block_col_idx in np.arange(start_col, end_col):
                     neighbor += n2d_array[block_row_idx, block_col_idx]
             nbrs_count[row_idx, col_idx] = neighbor - n2d_array[row_idx, col_idx]
     return nbrs_count
```

I found out that my implementation is very slow compared to `scipy.signal.convolve2d`:

```
def neighbors_count2(n2d_array, radii=1):
    from scipy.signal import convolve2d
    diameter = 2 * radii + 1
    n2d_array = n2d_array.astype(bool)
    nbrs_count = convolve2d(n2d_array, np.ones((diameter, diameter)),
                            mode='same', boundary='fill') - n2d_array
    return nbrs_count
```

Here is `%timeit` result in my computer:

```
%timeit -n 10 neighbors_count(np.random.randint(2, size=(100,100)))
10 loops, best of 3: 232 ms per loop

%timeit -n 10 neighbors_count2(np.random.randint(2, size=(100,100)))
10 loops, best of 3: 963 µs per loop
```

How to improve/vectorize my code so it can run faster than `scipy.signal.convolve2d`?

Comment: See [separable filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_filter) for now.  I am sure someone with more experience in Python will help you with the rest.

Comment: Ok, I see that it can be separated into two vectors.

Comment: How is it implemented in C? The same loop structure as I wrote in Python?

Comment: I deleted my comment as I found the Python interface, but it's written in C. You can check the [source](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html)... which links to a .py file that then links to the [C file](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.0/scipy/signal/sigtoolsmodule.c#L1023).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your algorithmic approach to improve your speed.

Currently:

- look at every cell
- lookup every neighbor-cell
- write the number of neighbors

My proposition:
You start with a zero-ed `nbrs_count` array and look at every cell. If it's occupied, increase the `nbrs_count` of all neighboring cells (you will get a huge speedup if the array is mostly empty).

To prevent all your conditional statements, you can simply use a `try: ... except:` block, as suggested by **@JoeWallis**

---

Here is an implementation using my propositions:

```python
import numpy as np

def neighbors_count(n2d_array, radii=1):
    assert n2d_array.ndim == 2

    nbrs_count = np.zeros_like(n2d_array)

    # array of adjacents cells
    adjacents = []
    for i in range(-radii, radii + 1):
        for j in range(-radii, radii + 1):
            if j != 0 or i != 0:
                adjacents.append((i,j))

    for (row_idx, col_idx), value in np.ndenumerate(n2d_array):
        if value:
            for i, j in adjacents:
                try:
                    if row_idx + i >= 0 and col_idx + j >= 0:
                        # because a negative index doesn't fail
                        nbrs_count[row_idx + i, col_idx + j] += 1
                except IndexError:
                    # We are outside the array
                    pass

    return nbrs_count
```

This solution is about 5 times faster than the original code (which is still way slower than scipy)

Comment: I don't see that will increase speed because it will read once and write many times instead of read many and write once. Writing is slower than reading.

Comment: You are already writing many times your `neighbor` variable, I don't think that writing `nbrs_count[row_idx, col_idx]` will be so much slower

Comment: I've implemented my proposition: please have a look at my updated answer

Comment: I see your point but still not enough speed up.

Comment: Well, trying to beat `C` using `Python` seems quite ambitious...

Comment: I wonder is there any better algorithms or data structures like trees?

Comment: You should take a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/108121/80949

Comment: I was thinking about this, rather than extending the array, you could do a `try` `except`.
`nbrs_count = np.zeros_like(array)`, and `try: nbrs_count[row_idx + i, col_idx + j] += 1`.
This would just make the entire function easier to read,
as `row_idx + i + radii` is weird without the comment.
And `nbrs_count = np.delete(nbrs...)` will not work with `radii > 1`.

Comment: @JoeWallis good idea, I updated my answer. (I also tried to remove the `try` with a complete `if` condition, but it ended up being slower...)

Comment: I forgot about `arr[-1]` being valid so it's not as nice as I thought it was, but the solution seems much nicer now, +1

Answer (score 2):

So to get the questions out of the way first.

> Why scipy.signal.convolve2D so fast?

SciPy and Co. all are programmed in C, with a Python interface.
As almost everyone knows interpreted languages are slow compared to compiled languages for the most part and will explain the difference in speed.
For a very small seemingly unbiased comparison of C vs Python,
you can look at the [Julia](http://julialang.org/) home page.
It says Python can range from 15 to 30 times slower than C,
again over a small set of functions and excluding anomaly's.

> How to improve/vectorize my code so it can run faster than `scipy.signal.convolve2d`?

Unless you want a complete re-write of your entire game of life in say C/C++, good luck.

---

- It's best to not use `assert`, 
  as they get ignored when you call the script with the [`-O`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4777156/2044866) flag.
- Limit the length of your lines.
  *79* is the common maximum character width in Python.
- Python prefers to have white-space over clumped up code,
  so when using operators try to leave a space either side of them.
  `1-1` looks like a variable not like `1 - 1`.
  This is worse since `1` can look like `l` in some typefaces.
- You should change the turnery operators:

  - Expand them over multiple lines, to increase readability;
  - Change them to use a function, so you don't calculate `row_idx - radii` twice; or,
  - Use `min` and `max`. Which gains the benefits of both the above.
- [You assume that you have \$O(1)\$ writes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/93267/42401#comment199916_108719), `neighbour` has \$O(3^2\times\text{n2d_array})\$ reads *and* writes.
  You are computing and *writing* to `start_row` and `end_row` way more then you need to, try putting them in the above `for` loop.
- Your sum for `neighbour` can be written nicer using a comprehension and `sum`,
  but you may loose some performance.
- Some of your variable names should probably change, `idx` can just be `index`,
  and `end_row` seems more like a function name than the `row_end`.

I would write your code as the following:

```
def neighbours_count(array, radii=1):
    if array.ndim != 2:
        raise Exception # Change this to a better Exception

    row_size, column_size = array.shape
    neighbours_amount = np.zeros_like(array)
    for row_index, row_value in enumerate(array):
        row_start = max(row_index - radii, 0)
        row_end = min(row_index + radii + 1, row_size)
        for column_index, column_value in enumerate(row_value):
            column_start = max(column_index - radii, 0)
            column_end = min(column_index + radii + 1, column_size)

            neighbours_amount[row_index, column_index] = sum(
                array[i, j]
                for i in np.arange(start_row, end_row)
                for j in np.arange(start_column, end_column)
            ) - array[row_index, column_index]

    return neighbours_amount
```

As there is no feasible way to make Python outperform `scipy.signal.convolve2d`
I didn't improve the performance.

Instead I would recommend either:

1. Don't re-invent the wheel and use `scipy.signal.convolve2d`, or;
2. Use @oliverpool's [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/108719/42401).

Comment: `assert` is ignored when `-O` is used in Python 2 or Python 3, according to https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement and https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement

Comment: How about using tree structure like hashlife? Will it increase performance?

Comment: @inyoot Python is a tool for fast development time. It is _not_ meant to execute fast. Also you only provided one function, I cannot review or make implementations of code I have no clue about.

Comment: I just wondering is the speed-up mainly because of compiled language or using better algorithm and data structure?

Comment: @inyoot I don't know enough about the algorithm they use, but C can run 15-30 times faster than Python, also you can do some fancy stuff in it to make it faster. If you just want execution speed then compiled languages are generally faster than interpreted languages. I would assume if you wrote oliverpool's code in C it would have roughly the same speed.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I will try to implement Oliverpool's in C and report the result.